# Prove of inequality under a Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $x\neq y$ when $x,y\in H$ and H is a Hilbert space which satisfy $\|x\|=\|y\|=r$. Show that $\|\frac{x+y}{2}\|<r$.

Actually in my question r=1 but as far as i could understand there is a way to prove this for any r. Is this true?

I tried to go with showing that $\|tx+(1-t)y\|<r$ where $t=\frac{1}{2}$ to no avail. Am I in a good direction? can someone point out the trick?

Comment: I would try using the triangle inequality, though I could be wrong.

Comment: Hint: $||x+y||^2+||x-y||^2=2||x||^2+2||y||^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use paralleogram law for $\frac{x}{2}$ and $\frac{y}{2}$ to obtain 
$||\frac{x+y}{2}||^2 + ||\frac{x-y}{2}||^2 = \frac{1}{2}||x||^2 + \frac{1}{2}||y||^2$ and so you get $1$ in the right hand side. Since the LHS is a sum of two non-negative terms, you get the desired inequality since $x\neq y$
.

Comment: Left Hand Side.

Answer (score 3):

So this is my final answer for any interested party answer and thank you @joy

$\|\frac{x+y}{2}\|^2 \leq \|\frac{x+y}{2}\|^2 + \|\frac{x-y}{2}\|^2 = \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2+\frac{1}{2}\|y\|^2$

and since $x \neq y$:

$\|\frac{x+y}{2}\|^2 < \frac{1}{2}\|x\|^2+\frac{1}{2}\|y\|^2=\frac{1}{2}r^2+\frac{1}{2}r^2=r^2$

Hence:

$\|\frac{x+y}{2}\| < r$

Comment: Yes... this proves for any $r$